# While attempting to calculate D for an RSA implementation, D always comes out negative

Tags: c++, encryption, rsa

I am trying to calculate d for RSA using the extended euclidean algorithm. However, everytime I run in it turns out to be negative.

This is the code for the algorithm, provided a is phi and e is 65537:

```
BigInteger exEuc(BigInteger a, BigInteger b){
    BigInteger x = 0;
    BigInteger prevX = 1; //holds the previous value of x
    BigInteger y = 1;
    BigInteger prevY = 0; //holds the previous value of y
    BigInteger temp, q;
        while(b != 0){
            q = a / b;
            temp = b;
            b = a % b;
            a = temp;
            temp = x;
            x = prevX-q*x;
            prevX = temp;
            temp = y;
            y = prevY-q*y;
            prevY = temp;
      }
      return prevY; //this ends up being d
}
```

I have tested the result using e*d mod phi which gives 1 like it's supposed to but I know d is not supposed to be negative. Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried using an *unsigned* big number? Or printing it as an *unsigned* number?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger, to figure out where, and why, it ends up being negative?

Comment: Yes, that's the way the Euclidean algorithm works. For computing inverses, where you always want the positive remainder, [you need to add `b` to the answer if it is negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Computing_multiplicative_inverses_in_modular_structures).

Comment: The number remains negative when I add a OR b back, and in both cases the e*dmodphi=1 test fails when I try

Comment: I don't what you're saying, but if you add `phi` to d it will be positive and e*d will equal 1 mod phi.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your implementation of the extended Euclidean algorithm, as shown by the fact that it gives a correct modular inverse `d` for the encryption exponent `e`.

However, for RSA, you do want a *positive* value for `d`.  To get that, simply let:

```
d = exEuc(phi, e) % phi;
```

That's assuming that the `%` operator for your BigInteger library always returns a non-negative result.  If that's not the case, then at least the result should be greater than `-phi`, in which case you can simply do:

```
d = exEuc(phi, e) % phi;
if ( d < 0 ) d += phi;
```

This works because, in [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), adding or subtracting (an integer multiple of) the modulus does not change the congruence class of a number.  In particular, if `(d*e) % phi == 1`, then also `((d+phi)*e) % phi == 1`.

---

BTW, there's a couple of optimizations you can make to your `exEuc()` code.  The first one is that you're not actually using the `x` and `prevX` values for anything in the end, so you can simply get rid of them entirely, like this:

```
BigInteger exEuc(BigInteger a, BigInteger b){
    BigInteger y = 1;
    BigInteger prevY = 0; //holds the previous value of y
    BigInteger temp, q;
        while(b != 0){
            q = a / b;
            temp = b;
            b = a % b;
            a = temp;
            temp = y;
            y = prevY-q*y;
            prevY = temp;
      }
      return prevY; //this ends up being d
}
```

The second optimization is that, since we're only interested in the result modulo `phi`, we can actually reduce `y` modulo `phi` any time we want during the calculation to keep it from getting too large (or negative!):

```
// calculate the modular inverse of x modulo m
BigInteger modInv(BigInteger x, BigInteger m){
    BigInteger a = x, b = m;
    BigInteger y = 1;
    BigInteger prevY = 0; //holds the previous value of y
    BigInteger temp, q;
        while(b != 0){
            q = a / b;
            temp = b;
            b = a % b;
            a = temp;
            temp = y;
            y = (prevY-q*y) % m;
            prevY = temp;
      }
      if ( prevY < 0 ) prevY += m;  // may or may not be necessary
      return prevY; // this ends up being d
}
```

(Note that I renamed the function and its arguments to be a bit more descriptive of what the optimized version actually does.  Also note that I included an extra test to make sure that the return value cannot be negative even if your BigInteger library's `%` operator may return negative values.)